# How to list childNodes names?

Tags: javascript

I have some sample website and I want to  display the number of child nodes in the entire document and in the body node. 
I manage to do it using code:

```
   var childDoc = document.childNodes.length;
   alert("Document have " + childDoc + " child nodes");

   var childDoc2 = document.body.childNodes.length;
   alert("Body have " + childDoc2 + " child nodes");
```

Now I need  to list those nodes names but i dont know how. Can anyone help me?

EDIT. 
working solution

```
var bodyChilds = document.body.childNodes;
var strg = "";

for(var i=0; i < bodyChilds.length; i++){
strg = strg + bodyChilds[i].nodeName + "\n";
}

alert (strg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple loop and array index. 
You can read more here : [ChildNodes](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/childNodes)

```
for (var i=0;i<document.body.childNodes.length;i++)
    { 
       //current node in childNodes[i]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the each childs (tag) name

```
var bodyChilds = document.body.childNodes;
var tagNames = [];
var localNames = [];
var nodeNames = [];
for(var i=0; i<bodyChilds.length; i++){
   // note: tag name will be undefined when is a text node
   //Here you can check null/undefined and take decision according to your need
   tagNames.push(bodyChilds[i].tagName);  
   localNames.push(bodyChilds[i].localName) //Name provided by developer in html
   nodeNames.push(bodyChilds[i].nodeName)
}
console.log(tagNames);
console.log(localNames);
console.log(nodeNames);
```

Comment: how to display them in the alert? in list?

Comment: This code will display in your console.log. if you wish to use alert instead just change the console.log to alert then add the .join(',') because it's array. 
For example:
console.log(tagNames) to alert(tagNames.join(','))

Comment: how its possible that counter show me 31 and there is only 11 tags on the list? + 20 colons

Comment: Some of them are text element. Text element not have a tagName so you should check nodeNames instead.